# Save date in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, calendar

Is there any simple idea to create calendar which enable user to select a date and keep it in database?

I'm creating a system, online car rental. So far, everything looks ok, but i get stuck implementing booking date.

Comment: checkout jquery UI calendar / Calendar control in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET framework includes a calendar control for this purpose. It's a combination textbox and Javascript based calendar. (I'm using the 4.0 framework, and there's a calendar control in the standard toolbox)

You should be able to store and set the value based on what's in your database.

There's also an Ajax enabled calendar control if you want to implement the AJAX Control toolkit.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Nice article and very helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use standart ms sql type `datetime`?

For calendar control in html, you can use jQuery UI datePicker - jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Winforms and WPF has such control in standart library